# How to capture current value of an outside variable when function is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, anonymous-function

Frequently, I am programmatically attaching handlers to elements within the DOM that rely on variables that may get changed later.

```
nextID = "#content-" + dataElement.elementBack;
something.on("change", function (e) {
    $(nextID).css({left: 0, position:'fixed', zindex: -1});
});
```

By the time this function is triggered, the value of nextID has changed and acts on the wrong element.

Is there a way to use the current value of a variable in a function at the time it is first defined or attached to an event?

(Please don't suggest that instead of nextID, I hardcode the element in there. If I would, I could.)

Comment: create a IIFE which will return you another function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround for this is using *self-invoked functions*:

```
nextID = "#content-" + dataElement.elementBack;

(function(nextID) {
    something.on("change", function (e) {
        $(nextID).css({left: 0, position:'fixed', zindex: -1});
    });
})(nextID);
```

Functions create new scopes in JavaScript, and since you give `nextID` as argument, `nextID` gets scoped and it'll be captured and available when the `change` event is triggered.

This is because JavaScript doesn't create scopes for any other language construct excepting functions. For example, a `for` like `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {}` won't create an scope and once the loop end, `i` is available in current scope and it will contain `10`.

I suggest you to take a look at [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) keyword part of next version of ECMA-Script (ECMA-Script 6) which will let us create block-scoped variables.

Comment: Great explanation. And crazy structure. It bends my brain like trying to figure out the plot of 12 Monkeys. Looking at @mohamedrias solution below, is that the same thing in a different form?

Comment: Yes, looking further and at this article on [Immediately-invoked function expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), I can see that these answers are similar. However, while I appreciate your explanation, I appreciate that the other answer keeps the structure in a recognizable and easily readable form.

Comment: @WesModes It's not that crazy and 12 monkeys wasn't too hard to understand haha BTW, my answer has a main advantage: if you want to add many event handlers in a code section, one self-invoked function would be enough for all event handlers instead of having to bind many self-invoked functions and capture many times `nextID`.

Comment: But if you start thinking about how Bruce Willis' character saw himself die as a child and how that inspired him to volunteer for the time-travel missions, it messes with your head and then you become a javascript programmer.

Comment: @WesModes You're the next Aristotheles :D

Comment: In the above convoluted code, can you indicate which are the params being passed in and which are the function parameters?

Comment: @WesModes I don't understand the question at all. BTW you might need to ask another question in SO if you want to clarify more concepts. For example, you can ask a new question and link to this previously published one so other visitors will know where to start investigating...

Answer (score 3):

You can create a IIFE which will bind the initial value of `nextID` to that function handler. Currently we're creating a closure where the variable value is scoped to the inner returned function.

```
nextID = "#content-" + dataElement.elementBack;
something.on("change", (function(nextID) { 
    return function (e) {
        $(nextID).css({left: 0, position:'fixed', zindex: -1});
       }
    })(nextID)
);
```

Comment: Can you give more explanation about what is happening here and why the function captures the variable value at time it is declared?